# How to get a reference to .net documentation from inside visual studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio

It seems like a VERY, VERY simple feature that should probably be enabled by default, but after searching the web and looking for an extension, I still can't manage it.

I want to be able to see the .Net documentation page of a highlighted or hovered over or perhaps even suggested element- either as a preview, or a link.

For instance, If I am recommended methods for modifying a list, I want to be able to figure out what those methods do without going to the definition and working it out myself every time.

This is either a REDICULOUS oversight from VS developers, who are otherwise capable, or I am missing something... and for some reason it doesn't show up on any kind of google search I can think of.

Comment: Press the F1 key.

Comment: If (you wish to answer yourself) { acceptAnswer(yours); }
else { IWill(acceptAnswer(mine)); }
thankYou();

Comment: @BetterLifeexe - I appreciate the attempt at humour but only you can accept an answer.

Comment: @phuzi wasn't saying he should accept his answer, I was saying if he answered, I would accept it.

Comment: @BetterLifeexe Ah, something got lost in translation. Thought you were saying that Hans should accept either there's or yours. Not the other way round. Sorry.